# Angular 4: Using modules and component imported in SharedModule, in Feature modules

Tags: angular

Problem is, I have `SharedModule` and `ProtectedModule` and I want to use `module`s and `component`s of `SharedModule` in `module`s and `component`s of `ProtectedModule`;

**shared.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule, Http } from '@angular/http';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';

import { ComponentsModule } from './components/components.module';
import { DirectivesModule } from './directives/directives.module';
import { PipesModule } from './pipes/pipes.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    Http,
    ComponentsModule,
    DirectivesModule,
    PipesModule
  ],
  exports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    Http,
    TranslateModule,
    ComponentsModule,
    DirectivesModule,
    PipesModule
  ],
  declarations: []
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

**protected.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';
import { ProtectedRoutingModule } from './protected-routing.module';
import { ProtectedComponent } from './protected.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { LoginService } from './login/login.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    ProtectedRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    ProtectedComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    SharedModule
  ],
  providers: [
    LoginService
  ]
})
export class ProtectedModule { }
```

And I have `login.service.ts` where I want use `HttpModule` imported in `SharedModule` that imported into `ProtectedModule` and `LoginService` imported into `ProtectedModule`.

**login.service.t**s:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {

  private loginUrl = 'http://localhost/kpittu/index.php/user/authorization';

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  login(): void {

  }

}
```

When I using `HttpModule` in `login.service.ts` there is an error:

> "cannot find name Http"

EDIT:

**Angular version:**

```
@angular/cli: 1.2.0
node: 8.0.0
os: linux x64
@angular/animations: 4.3.6
@angular/common: 4.3.6
@angular/compiler: 4.3.6
@angular/core: 4.3.6
@angular/forms: 4.3.6
@angular/http: 4.3.6
@angular/platform-browser: 4.3.6
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.3.6
@angular/router: 4.3.6
@angular/cli: 1.2.0
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.3.6
@angular/language-service: 4.3.6
```

Comment: Setup looks correct, what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: In `login.service.ts` `constructor(private http: Http) { }`: "cannot find name Http"

Comment: Your angular version?

Comment: Your login service has missing import:  import { Http } from '@angular/http';

Comment: see EDIT section please :-|

Comment: @SumitAgarwal: Yes but I import it in `SharedModule`

Comment: You have imported "HttpModule" which allows you to use the features of that module. But you need to import "Http" in the corresponding file.

Comment: how do you expect a class to be imported out of the box when you haven't really imported?

Comment: Too late to reply, even I too missed that you did not import Http

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing import in `login.service.ts` , use the one mentioned below:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {

  private loginUrl = 'http://localhost/kpittu/index.php/user/authorization';

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  login(): void {

  }

}
```

**EDIT**

Explanation:
You have imported "HttpModule" which allows you to use the features of that module. But you need to import "Http" in the corresponding file.

Correct version of `sharedModule` , you don't need to import Http here unless your are using it here.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';

import { ComponentsModule } from './components/components.module';
import { DirectivesModule } from './directives/directives.module';
import { PipesModule } from './pipes/pipes.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    ComponentsModule,
    DirectivesModule,
    PipesModule
  ],
  exports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    TranslateModule,
    ComponentsModule,
    DirectivesModule,
    PipesModule
  ],
  declarations: []
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Comment: That's mean that I need import in `SharedModule` modules only, am I right?

Comment: Also I guess you need to go through the angular docs and understand the difference between file level import and Module imports. Both are two separate things/concepts.